# Raspbian stretchOs not booting

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

[image: Raspbian stretch]
Hello, 
I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 model B and I just installed Raspbian Stretch. Whenever I turn on the power, the system is not booting, all I can see is a picture of Raspberry fruits and a cursor blinking.
I can type here, but cannot login.

Comment: Did you use Raspbian Stretch dated 2017-09-07 ? What specification is your power supply ? Did you use Etcher to flash Raspbian to the sd card ? What size sd card ?

Comment: Yes Stretch dated 2017-09-07  I'm using a power bank output 5.0v -1.5A  yes I used Etcher to flash Raspbian and size of sdcard is 16gb class 4

Comment: I'd suggest getting the official 5.1Volt 2.5Amp 18awg cable power supply to get this working first. I suspect a power issue.

Comment: New problem  now my sdcard started to overheat How to find out that my Rpi is proper I recently bought it it's brand new

Comment: You could try to plug the SD Card into your computer and confirm if you can see the boot partition. I would recommend, however to just stop using it and get a new one (or return the one you have if you just bought it)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue like you before.Flush it again in Ubuntu desktop with balenaEtcher.Maybe it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you expanded the partition by gparted or other tools instead the raspi configuration tool it may cause the problem. Flash again the image in the sd card, and let only modify the partition size by the config tool. I took the answere from here http://www.zdnet.com/article/hands-on-with-raspbian-gnulinux-stretch-for-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.

Many a time, owners of a Rpi just cuts the power cord to the Rpi to turn it off. This will cause both the boot and rootfs partition on to (micro)SD or USB memory stick to become corrupted. To recover from such a filesystem corruption, insert the Rpi (micro)SD or USB memory stick to a Linux desktop computer and run **dosfsck -aw /dev/sdX1** (boot partition) and **fsck -fy /dev/sdX2** (rootfs partition) (where X is the device ID, i.e. /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdc1, etc.) to clean both the corrupted partitions. Then, plug back the (micro)SD or USB memory stick to the Rpi to see if it will boot OK.